# Is any package name restrictions applied in grails?

Tags: grails

I have created a Domain class called **Action** under package promotion

```
package promotion
class Action {

    String name
    String code
    String address
    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
        code maxSize:5
        address nullable:false
    }
}
```

**Issue:** Here my problem is I can not generate controller&views. And also I can not change default error messages from message property for my constraints
example: promotion.Action.name.nullable=Please enter the action name

**Note:** But if I change my package name "promotion" to something like "com.app.act" it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make package name little brief. So it can be a good coding practice also